# Capybara search: what's the new way?

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

My trusty array search methods decided to break after a bundle install update.

My old way:

```
def all_find_and_click(type,data)
...
  all(type).each do |elem|
    ...
    elem.click if elem.text == data
    ...
  end
end
```

Gets me this....

```
 NoMethodError:
 undefined method `each' for #<RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::All:0x3c416e8>
 # ./spec/features/capy_support.rb:25:in `all_find_and_click'
```

https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara

still shows all('a').each as a finding technique

```
 all('a').each { |a| a[:href] }
```

Here is my Gemfile.lock

```
GEM
remote: https://rubygems.org/
specs:
actionmailer (4.1.1)
  actionpack (= 4.1.1)
  actionview (= 4.1.1)
  mail (~> 2.5.4)
actionpack (4.1.1)
  actionview (= 4.1.1)
  activesupport (= 4.1.1)
  rack (~> 1.5.2)
  rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
actionview (4.1.1)
  activesupport (= 4.1.1)
  builder (~> 3.1)
  erubis (~> 2.7.0)
activemodel (4.1.1)
  activesupport (= 4.1.1)
  builder (~> 3.1)
activerecord (4.1.1)
  activemodel (= 4.1.1)
  activesupport (= 4.1.1)
  arel (~> 5.0.0)
activesupport (4.1.1)
  i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.9)
  json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
  minitest (~> 5.1)
  thread_safe (~> 0.1)
  tzinfo (~> 1.1)
arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
builder (3.2.2)
capybara (2.3.0)
  mime-types (>= 1.16)
  nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
  rack (>= 1.0.0)
  rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
  xpath (~> 2.0)
childprocess (0.5.3)
  ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.11)
cucumber (1.3.15)
  builder (>= 2.1.2)
  diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3)
  gherkin (~> 2.12)
  multi_json (>= 1.7.5, < 2.0)
  multi_test (>= 0.1.1)
cucumber-rails (1.4.1)
  capybara (>= 1.1.2, < 3)
  cucumber (>= 1.3.8, < 2)
  mime-types (~> 1.16)
  nokogiri (~> 1.5)
  rails (>= 3, < 5)
diff-lcs (1.2.5)
erubis (2.7.0)
ffi (1.9.3-x86-mingw32)
gherkin (2.12.2-x86-mingw32)
  multi_json (~> 1.3)
hike (1.2.3)
i18n (0.6.9)
json (1.8.1)
mail (2.5.4)
  mime-types (~> 1.16)
  treetop (~> 1.4.8)
mime-types (1.25.1)
mini_portile (0.6.0)
minitest (5.3.4)
multi_json (1.10.1)
multi_test (0.1.1)
nokogiri (1.6.2.1-x86-mingw32)
  mini_portile (= 0.6.0)
polyglot (0.3.5)
rack (1.5.2)
rack-test (0.6.2)
  rack (>= 1.0)
rails (4.1.1)
  actionmailer (= 4.1.1)
  actionpack (= 4.1.1)
  actionview (= 4.1.1)
  activemodel (= 4.1.1)
  activerecord (= 4.1.1)
  activesupport (= 4.1.1)
  bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
  railties (= 4.1.1)
  sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
railties (4.1.1)
  actionpack (= 4.1.1)
  activesupport (= 4.1.1)
  rake (>= 0.8.7)
  thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
rake (10.3.2)
rspec (3.0.0)
  rspec-core (~> 3.0.0)
  rspec-expectations (~> 3.0.0)
  rspec-mocks (~> 3.0.0)
rspec-core (3.0.1)
  rspec-support (~> 3.0.0)
rspec-expectations (3.0.1)
  diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
  rspec-support (~> 3.0.0)
rspec-mocks (3.0.1)
  rspec-support (~> 3.0.0)
rspec-rails (3.0.1)
  actionpack (>= 3.0)
  activesupport (>= 3.0)
  railties (>= 3.0)
  rspec-core (~> 3.0.0)
  rspec-expectations (~> 3.0.0)
  rspec-mocks (~> 3.0.0)
  rspec-support (~> 3.0.0)
rspec-support (3.0.0)
rubyzip (1.1.4)
selenium-webdriver (2.42.0)
  childprocess (>= 0.5.0)
  multi_json (~> 1.0)
  rubyzip (~> 1.0)
  websocket (~> 1.0.4)
sprockets (2.12.1)
  hike (~> 1.2)
  multi_json (~> 1.0)
  rack (~> 1.0)
  tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
sprockets-rails (2.1.3)
  actionpack (>= 3.0)
  activesupport (>= 3.0)
  sprockets (~> 2.8)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.4)
tilt (1.4.1)
treetop (1.4.15)
  polyglot
  polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
tzinfo (1.2.1)
  thread_safe (~> 0.1)
websocket (1.0.7)
xpath (2.0.0)
  nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  x86-mingw32

DEPENDENCIES
  capybara
  cucumber
  cucumber-rails
  rails
  rspec
  rspec-rails
  selenium-webdriver
```

Any ideas?

Comment: the error says that `all` is an rspec matcher, not a capybara finder. So you're not getting back what you think you're getting. What gems did you update?

Comment: I added a domino gem which I removed hoping the toothpaste would go back into the tube.  I updated the question and included my Gemfile.lock

Comment: Update: I found a working copy and enforced the selenium and capybara versions and get the same error. gem 'capybara', '2.2.1', gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.39.0'

Comment: Were you using rspec-expectations v3 before? They added an `all` method that is likely conflicting with Capybara's `all`.

Comment: Probably not, let me see if I can roll it back

Comment: I dialed it back to 2.0.1, to no effect. The same error occurs

Comment: What did you dial back to 2.0.1? As far as I can see BuiltIn::All, was not added to rspec/expectations until v3.0. So I do not see how you could get the same error message. It will likely help to expand your shared code so that it reproduces the problem (ex where the method lives and how it is used in your tests).

Comment: What kind of spec is this ? Capybara's DSL is no longer included in controller specs by default